# Esc Pos how to know if print job is ended

Tags: printing, serial-port, thermal-printer

Is there any method to understand if a ESC POS print job via serial cable is ended?
I know there is some status query to send to printer, but I could not find any for understand if the print job is end (or print buffer is empty).

Comment: Did you found a reliable method on this issue? I currently detect end of transmission character (0x04) - does not seems to work for every printer. In other hand, in this article [http://goo.gl/zplAFv] it is said that every printer may have its own "end of print job condition"

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I did not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could check CTS signal before sending the command, and then return true from your method if the command was executed